# Have shift act as state key (like iOS keyboard?)

Tags: cocoa, macos

It occurred to me today that I could type more efficiently if the shift key on my Mac desktop keyboard behaved the same way as the iOS keyboard.

When I press shift, the next character would get capitalized (added behavior). If I hold down shift, all typed keys would be capitalized (current behavior).

This config has the advantage that you don't have to hold down shift in order to make capitalization occur. Usually you only want to cap one key at a time anyway.

Or if you don't know, anyone have thoughts to point me in the right direction? I have PCKeyboardHack, but that is just remapping, whereas this question is about new behavior (I think).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

System Preferences -> Universal Access -> Sticky Keys: On

Comment: Perfect answer, and man does that make me feel dumb... Thanks!